# Changing MasterDetail Height With A Custom Renderer

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am currently trying to change the height of the default MasterDetailPage using the material design with FormsAppCompatActivity.

Basically I got the custom renderer to work, but I am trying to resize it  dynamically based on toolbar size. The reason being is that different devices have different sized toolbars. Furthermore, I got the resizing to work but the black shadow that comes with the **MasterDetailPage** stays in place and does not seem to pass through the AddView function.

```
bool firstDone;
     public override void AddView(Android.Views.View child)//Android.Views.View
     {
         var padding = child.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("TopPadding").GetValue(child);//tried padding but did not work
         if (firstDone)
         {
             LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams)child.LayoutParameters;
             //p.TopMargin = padding;
             p.TopMargin = 200;// Need this to be dynamic for different devices
             base.AddView(child, p);
         }
         else
         {
             firstDone = true;
             base.AddView(child);
         }
     }
```

[image: sample result]

Comment: Hi, can you give me a simple of your project?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Yeah, how should I send it and which part?

Comment: You can use OneDrive or github.  So I can reproduce your problem based your project.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT I uploaded 
 it to github, also it was made with vs 2017 https://github.com/TheBuilder3/SampleProject_MasterDetail

Comment: Hi, sorry, I am late, and I have found how to remove the shadow.